# find the saddle point of a matrix using pointers

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, matrix

An N × M matrix is said to have a saddle point if some entry a[i][j] is the smallest in row i and the largest in column j.  In the following example, 7 is the saddle point:

```
    1 2 3
a = 4 5 6
    7 8 9
```

The complexity of the function should be O(n log n).

The required function prototype is:

```
int solution(int **A, int N, int M )
```

My code:

```
int solution(int **A, int N ,int M)
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    int P_row=0,P_col=0, flag=0;
    node * matrix= (*A);

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        P_row=i;
        P_row=j;
        flag=0;

        for(j=0;j<M;j++)
        if(matrix[i][j]< matrix[P_row][P_col])
        {
            P_row=i;
            P_row=j;
        }

        for(k=0;k<N;k++)
        {
            if(matrix[k][P_col]> matrix[P_row][P_col])
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==0)
            break;
        j=0;
    }
    if(flag==0)
        printf("\n The saddle point is %d at row=%d col=%d", matrix[P_row][P_col],P_row,P_col);
    else
        printf("there was no saddle point");
}
```

When I'm running the code I am getting compilation errors in line 5, line 14, line 22 where I have specified if conditions inside nested for loops. Please tell me where to modify my code according the to given input parameters.

Comment: You should be able to just create two arrays representing the maxima among the columns and the minima among the rows. Then determining a saddle point is `O(M*N)` to build those arrays and `O(M+N)` to determine the saddle point. As it is, you're recomputing the column maxima in every row.

Comment: What is your actual question? Does this code you have provided fail? If so then where? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: When you find the point, your code reads `P_row = i; P_row = j;`. This makes the first assignment useless and also looks suspicious: Replace `P_row = j` with `P_col = j` in the two places where it occurs.

Comment: Cosmetic advice: When you print out something, please put the newline character at the end of the format string, so that output always terminates with a line break.

Comment: Since your function returns `void` and the required prototype returns `int`, your code immediately fails any marking grade.

Comment: Now you've fixed the return type from `void` to `int`, but it shouldn't compile without warnings because you don't have `return matrix[P_row][P_col];` or something similar to actually return a value.  Which compiler are you using — because you aren't making it give you enough warnings.

Comment: post the compilation errors (preferably with the line failing as line numbers in a code snippet aren't ideal)

Comment: "The complexity of the function should be O(n log n)." - what is n?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for your example:
P_row=i;
P_row=j; This is clearly an easily fixable mistake.

```
#include <cstdio>

int solution(int **A, int N, int M );

int A1[] = {1, 2, 3};
int A2[] = {4, 5, 6};
int A3[] = {7, 8, 9};

int* A[] ={A1, A2, A3};
int main()
{
    solution(A, 3, 3);
}
typedef int** node;


int solution(int **A, int N ,int M)
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    int P_row=0,P_col=0, flag=0;
    node matrix= (A);

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        P_row=i;
        P_col=j;
        flag=0;

        for(j=0;j<M;j++)
        if(matrix[i][j]< matrix[P_row][P_col])
        {
            P_row=i;
            P_col=j;
        }

        for(k=0;k<N;k++)
        {
            if(matrix[k][P_col]> matrix[P_row][P_col])
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==0)
            break;
        j=0;
    }
    if(flag==0)
        printf("\n The saddle point is %d at row=%d col=%d", matrix[P_row][P_col],P_row,P_col);
    else
        printf("there was no saddle point");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey Geo, your answer just got deleted on this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949066/create-a-cycle-out-of-scattered-points - if you like you can undelete it - after your edit it was definitely a fine answer and should not have been deleted. I suspect you method *might* work even if the points are completely random