# Create a cycle out of scattered points

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I know this sounds trivial, but my head is refusing to give an algorithm for this.

I have a bunch of points scattered on a 2-D plane and want to store them in a list such that they create a ring. The points do not belong on a cycle.

[image]

Start from the first point in the list (red in this pic) and sequentially add the rest based on their distance.

Since I cannot answer my question I will post here a possible answer.

This is an approach that seems to do the job. 
V.pos holds the positions of the nodes and distance() is just a function that returns the Euclidean distance between two points. A faster approach would also delete the next_node after appending it to the ring so that you don't have to go through the already connected points

`ring = [nodes[0]]
    while len(ring) < len(nodes): 
        minl=99999
        for i in range(len(nodes)):
            dist = distance(V.pos[ring[-1]],V.pos[nodes[i]])
            if dist<minl  and nodes[i] not in ring: 
                minl = dist
                next_node = nodes[i]
        ring.append(next_node)`

Comment: Seems a bit to broad for the Stackoverflow platform. Can you narrow it down to a bit more specific then "any ideas?"

Comment: You have just described an algorithm: *"Start from the first point in the list and sequentially add the rest based on their distance."* Why not try implementing that?

Comment: It can be a bit confusing to avoid having taking an already connected point and closing the cycle in the end. But, yes, I have the outline of the algorithm in my mind and I'm trying to implement it, just with no great success up untli now.

Comment: I also wanted to say sorry if the question is not properly formed, but it's the 1st time I'm using stachkoverflow and I'm neither a pro programmer nor a native english speaker...

Comment: @user, the reason your question is getting downvoted is because it's in the form "I want to do X, how do I do it?", where as we prefer "I want to do X, I'm approaching the problem using a particular method Y, here's my code, but I'm struggling with this specific part Z"

Comment: @OGHaza Well, it's my first post, I will try to get better in the future. My comment on M Oehm's  answer describes my approach

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea that will give okay-ish results if your point cloud is already ring-shaped like your example:

- Determine a centre point; this can either be the centre of gravity of all points or the centre of the bounding box.
- Represent all points in radial coordinates (radius, angle) with reference to the centre
- Sort by angle

This will, of course, produce jagged stars for random clouds, but it is not clear, what exactly a "ring" is. You could probably use this as a first draft and start swapping nodes if that gives you a shorter overall distance. Maybe this simple code is all you need short of implementing the minimum distance over all nodes of a graph.

Anayway, here goes:

```
import math

points = [(0, 4), (2, 2), ...]     # original points in Cartesian coords    
radial = []                        # list of tuples(index, angle)

# find centre point (centre of gravity)
x0, y0 = 0, 0
for x, y in points:
    x0 += x
    y0 += y

x0 = 1.0 * x0 / len(points)
y0 = 1.0 * y0 / len(points)

# calculate angles
for i, p in enumerate(points):
    x, y = p
    phi = math.atan2(y - y0, x - x0)

    radial += [(i, phi)]

# sort by angle
def rsort(a, b):
    """Sorting criterion for angles"""
    return cmp(a[1], b[1])

radial.sort(rsort)

# extract indices
ring = [a[0] for a in radial]
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Oehm. Unfortunately my reputation is not good enough to vote for your answer. My implementation was going towards something much more simplistc and primitive. I populate a "ring" list by taking the first of point in my list of random points. Then find the point with the minimum distance between the last point in the  "ring" list and all the the random points list and then add it in the "ring". It's not the most efficient code but seems like it does the job. I will post it later that I will have some time